# How to clear the pre-login screen in Redstone 4 (Win 10 ver 1803) of all the "tips"?

Tags: windows-10

In Redstone 3, which I still run on some machines, the pre-login screen, i.e. the screen on which you tap or click so you get the password box to pop-up is just an image. In Redstone 4, Miscrosoft added some "useful" tips to this screen, along the lines of "do you like this image?" or "get entertainment from the Windows store" (or something like that). I don't know how take a screenshot of this pre-login screen, but if you doubt me, I can probably take a photo with my camera. Anyway, is  there a way to stop Redstone 4 from giving all these tips on the pre-login screen? When you actually click/tap somewhere other than on the tips, they do go away and the password box pops in. But I dislike the visual clutter these tips provide.

N.B.: after a bit more googling, it looks like the official name for this pre-login screen is the "lock screen".

Answer (score 0):

From the more elaborate answer linked: choosing something other than "[Windows Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Spotlight)" for Background of the Lock Screen (in Settings > Personalization) makes the tips go away for me in Redstone 4.

N.B. Microsoft has docs on this too: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-spotlight It looks like the ["fun facts"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/manage-tips-and-suggestions) (official name of this tips feature) cannot be disabled in the Pro version without disabling the Spotlight altogether; I kinda liked Spotlight because it provides new images now and then, but the "fun facts" can be turned off in Enterprise and Education versions--it actually defaults to off in the latter (*)--while keeping Spotlight on (Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific default lock screen image > Turn off fun facts, tips, tricks, and more on lock screen).

[image]

(*) because education cannot contain fun facts, as we all know